# Is there any way to tweak output of keras Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, oop, keras, autoencoder

I was trying to make a recommender engine using Stacked Autoencoder. I am using the movielens dataset.
Below is the sample dataset. Row-indices are Users and Column indices are Movies. Each cell contains a rating of a movie given by a user between 1 to 5, 0 represents that the user didn't watch that movie.

```
mat = array([[[0. , 3.5, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]],
       [[0. , 0. , 4. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]],
       [[4. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]],
       [[0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 3. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 4. ]],
       [[0. , 3. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ]]], dtype=float32)
```

Now I built an autoencoder but this autoencoder trains for whole data but I didn't want it to train on where the user didn't rate(cell with 0 value) so I want to change the output of model such that indices, where the 0 is in original data, become 0 after each epoch but that throws me a @property error. Is there any way to tweak the output? or is there any way to make a setter function for this _output variable?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras 
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras import Model
import numpy as np

def build_model(input_shape,train=True):
    getin = Input(input_shape)
    encoder = Dense(128,activation='sigmoid')(getin)
    encoder = Dense(64,activation='sigmoid')(encoder)
    encoder = Dense(32,activation='sigmoid')(encoder)
    decoder = Dense(64,activation='sigmoid')(encoder)
    decoder = Dense(128,activation='sigmoid')(decoder)
    decoder = Dense(input_shape,activation='sigmoid',name='op')(decoder)
    model = Model(inputs=getin,outputs=decoder)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error')
    return model
model = build_model(mat[0].shape[1])

for i in range(50):   #for epochs
    model.fit(mat,mat,epochs=1) #fitting the model
    model.output = tf.multiply(model.output,tf.cast(mat==0,tf.float32)) #Now changing some values of trained output tensor to zero where original dataset contains zero
```

Error message -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   2548       try:
-> 2549         super(tracking.AutoTrackable, self).__setattr__(name, value)
   2550       except AttributeError:

AttributeError: can't set attribute

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-379ab2b4f62f> in <module>
      1 for _ in range(2):
      2     model.fit(mat,mat,epochs=1,batch_size=100)
----> 3     model.output = tf.multiply(model.output,tf.cast(mat==0,tf.float32))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
    454                          ' Always start with this line.'), None)
    455 
--> 456     super(Network, self).__setattr__(name, value)
    457 
    458     # Keep track of metric instance created in subclassed model/layer.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   2552             ('Can\'t set the attribute "{}", likely because it conflicts with '
   2553              'an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a '
-> 2554              'different name.').format(name))
   2555       return
   2556 

AttributeError: Can't set the attribute "output", likely because it conflicts with an existing read-only @property of the object. Please choose a different name.
```

Update - Got a PyTorch solution.

mat =
class SAE(nn.Module):
def **init**(self):
super(SAE,self).**init**()
self.fc1 = Linear(nmovie,50)
self.fc2 = Linear(50,25)
self.fc3 = Linear(25,10)
self.fc4 = Linear(10,25)
self.fc5 = Linear(25,50)
self.fc6 = Linear(50,nmovie)
self.activation = nn.Sigmoid()
def forward(self,x):
x = self.activation(self.fc1(x))
x = self.activation(self.fc2(x))
x = self.activation(self.fc3(x))
x = self.activation(self.fc4(x))
x = self.activation(self.fc5(x))
x = self.fc6(x)
return x

```
sae = SAE()
sae.cuda()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
opt = optim.RMSprop(sae.parameters(),lr=0.1,weight_decay=0.2)

for epoch in range(1,50):
    train_loss = 0
    s = 0.
    for i in range(nuser):
        getin = mat[i].unsqueeze(0)
        target = getin.clone()
        if torch.sum(target.data >0) > 0:
            output = sae(getin)
            target.require_grad = False

#This is what I want

            output[target==0] = 0 #Some output getting zero

            loss= criterion(output, target)
            mean_corrector = nmovie/float(torch.sum(target.data>0)+ 1e-10)
            loss.backward()
            train_loss += torch.sqrt(loss.data*mean_corrector)
            s+=1.
            opt.step()
    print('epoch: {}, loss: {}'.format(epoch,train_loss/s))
```

But still wondering how can I do this using Keras.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: @AMC sorry for the trouble. Is it clear now or should I try to add more details?